# How to download Yahoo email

Tags: yahoo-mail

There has been a conflict with my Realestate agent

I want to send her an old email as an evidence

she did not accept forwarded email and asked to send the email as an attachment (along with the attachements in the first email)

how can I download a single email from Yahoo mail including its attachemnets ?

Answer (score 1):

In the "···" menu, select "View raw message":

[image: Message actions menu showing "View raw message" highlighted]
[image: Email thread actions menu showing "View raw message" highlighted]

When the new page opens, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and save the text to a file.

Finally, rename the file from `.txt` to `.eml`.